# Solving algebraically a cubic inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any way to solve algebraically the following  inequality:

$x-x^{3}+x^{2}-5 \geq 0$.

I know the answer is $x \leq -1.594$ because I have plotted the function but I can't figure out how to do it algebraically.

I have already learnt how to solve quadratic inequalities by doing a table of signs but I'm stuck with this one since I don't know how to find the roots to make the table of signs.

Comment: Here (click exact form)  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Dx-x%5E3%2Bx%5E2-5

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a convenient solution to cubics that is comparable to the quadratic formula you are familiar with.

Comment: It is more common to say degree rather than grade.

Comment: @SimpleArt Yeah I thought that the question was an inequality for grade 3 students or something.

Comment: You can use Calculus to find max and min then use a numerical method like Newton's. Alternatively, you can use Cardano's formula:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

Answer (score 0):

Start by finding the root, which is given [here.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Dx-x%5E3%2Bx%5E2-5)  You may click "exact form" if you want the radicals.

The exact solution is given as:

$$x\le\frac13\left(1-\sqrt[3]{62-6\sqrt{105}}-\frac{2\sqrt[3]{4}}{\sqrt[3]{31-3\sqrt{105}}}\right)$$

Then, use calculus to see that it is monotonic and decreasing from that root to negative infinity.  There is your solution.

Comment: The above result is given instantaneously by *Mathematica*'s `Solve[]` function.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Oh, that's even fancier.  :O

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=-x^3+x^2+x-5$$ and $$f'(x)=0\iff3x^3-2x-1=0$$ Therefore $f$ has a max. at $x=1$ with value $f(1)=-4$ and a min. at $x=-\frac 13$ with value $\approx -5.185$.Since $f(x)\gt 0$ for $x\lt x_0$ (*$|f(x)|$ goes to infinity when $|x|$ goes to infinity*) we have the answer $$f(x)\ge 0\space \text{for} \space x\le x_0$$
where $x_0$ is your value $\approx -1.594$.